# Copy data from one data frame and paste in column name corresponding to that value in a new Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, append

I have a data frame as shown below

```
df
           0                                            1
 0  Time Stamp                           2022-01-01 / 00:16:29
 1  - Server Connection                     OK
 2  - PC1 Number                            1
 3  - PC1 Main Status                       OK
 4  - PC1 Powermeter Value               4294954868 kWh
   ...  ... ...
 1046   - Coulpler Outlet N Temperature         17�C
 1047   Time Stamp                        2022-01-01 / 23:16:30
 1048   - Level Sensor Status   High
 1049   Time Stamp                        2022-01-01 / 23:16:34
 1050   Time Stamp                        2022-01-01 / 23:16:38
 1051 rows × 2 columns
```

I made another new data frame df2 with column names as the elements of 1st column of df (without repitition)

```
df2

Time Stamp  - Server Connection - PC1 Number    - PC1 Main Status   - PC1 Powermeter 
Value   - PC1 Power Module Status   - PC1 Input R Voltage   - PC1 Input S Voltage   - 
PC1 Input T Voltage - PC1 Top Temperature   ... - PC2 Cable Temperature

0 rows × 30 columns
```

Now i want to copy the values corresponsing to each column name into the new datafram.
Desired Output

```
 Time Stamp  Server Connection  PC Number  PC1 Main Status  PC1 Powermeter Value
 2022-01-01         OK                1            OK             4294954868 kWh
 / 00:16:29

2022-01-01         OK                1            OK               46868 kWh
/ 01:16:29
```

I tried using for loop like this but did not get the desired result

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    for j in column_names:
        if df[0][i]==column_names[j]:
            x = column_names[j]
            df2 = df2.append({x : df[1][i]}, ignore_index=True)
```

And if the TimeStamp value occurs with time gap of less than 5 mins to the last copied TimeStamp value, Ignore the TimeStamp.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

If `Tinmestamp` is always first value per groups use:

```
df = df.assign(g = df[0].eq('Time Stamp').cumsum()).pivot('g', 0, 1)
```

Comment: Hie. No...TimeStamp is not always the 1st value of the group...there are timeStamp values in between as well.

Comment: @PradyumnaTK - Unfortuantely then need create groups manually.